# How to recode page cms to show 2 column of 6 product instead of one column of 6 product

Tags: php, cms-block

How to recode page cms to show 2 column of 6 product instead of one column of 6 product

this is my current coding

{{block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" product_count=''99" pagination="1" centered="1" hide_button="1" block_name="New in Store"}}

{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="28" product_count="99" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 4], [960, 5], [1280, 6]" pagination="1" centered="1" hide_button="1" block_name="Our Featured Products"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="grid12-6">
```

CONTENT THAT YOU WANT IN COLUMN 1 HERE

```
</div>

<div class="grid12-6">
```

CONTENT THAT YOU WANT IN COLUMN 2 HERE

```
</div>
```

This basically just uses your theme's grid class to split the elements into 2 50% columns.

I'd strongly suggest not to allow product_count to be 99, that's a huge amount of products and images to load just for 1 slider and will cause your page load speed to increase massively.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. Now there is actually one coluum featuring 6 products.

I want to change it to 2 coluum featuring 6product in 1 coluum , total 12 product at one time.

Comment: The above code works, I have now edited to make it more general. The reason it did not work for you is because I am fairly sure the first block you're trying to include catalog/product_new is not valid.

Comment: Try this with any content you (that is valid) in the 2 div's as above and it will work as you wish.